# How to use sed to edit after the first occurrence of a certain character?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I created a very complicated sed command to remove parts that match certain patterns:

```
sed 's/...//Ig; s/...//Ig; s/...//Ig'
```

But I found that I made a mistake, I should only edit the part after the first occurrence of `:`.  How to modify this sed command and/or using other commands to achieve it?

The lines to edit are actually output of grep, e.g.:

```
/foo/bar:foobar
/foobar/foo/bar:foo_bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming for simplicity that you want to substitute each `foo` occurring **after** the first `:` with `FOO`.

```
sed 'h           # save the current line in the hold space
     s/[^:]*://  # delete everything up to the marker
     s/foo/FOO/g # YOUR COMPLICATED COMMAND GOES HERE
     x           # swap pattern and hold space
     s/:.*/:/    # delete from the first : to the end in the original line
     G           # append hold space (: with whatever follows it)
     s/\n//' yourfile # remove the newline that comes with G
```

The above code was updated upon the suggestion received in a comment.

The original answer is below. Even if in this case it's a bit of an overkill, it shows that you can use the null character in `sed`, `\x0`, as a "marker" that you can generally assume is not in a text file (in contrast to using e.g. `_xxx_` which could potentially be in a file already). **(This second version substitutes for occurrences of `foo` *before* `:`, in line with when I misread the question.**)

```
sed 'h           # save the current line in the hold space
     s/:/\x0:/   # mark the first : by prepending a null character
     s/.*\x0//   # delete everything up to the marker
     x           # swap pattern and hold space
     s/:.*//     # delete from the first : to the end in the original line
     s/foo/FOO/g # YOUR COMPLICATED COMMAND GOES HERE
     G           # append hold space (: with whatever follows it)
     s/\n//' yourfile # remove the newline that comes with G
```

Comment: To delete everything before the first :, you can do `s/[^:]*:/:/`

Comment: @Philippe, totally right! I fee so dumb now, ahahah.

Comment: `\x0` can be handy at lots of occasions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I should really try to remove `.*` from my muscle memory, as it brings me to think I need to emulate a non-greedy `*` instead of applying the normal/greedy one to the appropriate token.

Comment: The COMPLICATED COMMAND is now executed on the part before the `:`. Move that comand to the line before `x`, and it will be executed on the part after `:`.

Comment: @WalterA, thanks. I should also take more time to read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can be used here as better alternative:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {s=$1; $1=""; gsub(/a/, "@"); gsub(/o/, "0"); print s $0}' file
```

```
/foo/bar:f00b@r
/foobar/foo/bar:f00_b@r
```

Here we are splitting input using `:` and saving first field before `:` in a variable `s`. Then we run few `gsub` function to do all substitutions and finally we print saved variable with rest of the line.

Comment: Hi anubhava, the sed command is pretty complicated: sed 's/\(\(at[[:blank:]]\+\)\|\(@[[:blank:]]*\)\)foobar[[:blank:]]*\(\.\|dot\|\.dot\.\)[[:blank:]]*com//Ig; s/copyright[[:blank:]]*\((c)\|©\)*[-–[:blank:][:digit:]~,by]*foo[[:blank:]]*bar//Ig; s/com\.foobar\.//g', I'm not sure how to do the same pattern matching with gsub

Comment: Same `sed` pattern and replacement can be used directly in `gsub` function.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:/\n&/;h;s/foo/FOO/g;s/bar/BAR/g;y/-/_/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Introduce an newline before the first `:`.

Copy the result to the hold space (HS).

Substitute/translate globally one or more times.

Append the pattern space (PS) to the HS.

Replace the PS by the HS.

Remove the newlines and everything between them.

Answer (score 1):

First split each line of the `grep` output in 2 lines and perform your `sed` commands on the even lines.
It would look like

```
grep "something" list_of_file |
  sed 's/:/\n/' |
  sed '0~2s/...//Ig; 0~2s/...//Ig; 0~2s/...//Ig' |
  paste -d":" - -
```

With `0~2` you are telling `sed` to operate on even lines only.
Example:

```
grep -E "root|127" /etc/{passwd,hosts} |
   sed 's/:/\n/' |
   sed -r '0~2s/([0,o])/==\1==/g' | 
   paste -d":" - -
```

output:

```
/etc/passwd:r==o====o==t:x:==0==:==0==:r==o====o==t:/r==o====o==t:/bin/bash
/etc/hosts:127.==0==.==0==.1    l==o==calh==o==st
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl alternative. Here is one solution using positive lookbehind

```
$ cat grep_out.dat
/foo/bar:foobar
/foobar/foo/bar:foo_bar
$ perl -pe ' s/(?<=:)(foo)/\U\1/g ' grep_out.dat
/foo/bar:FOObar
/foobar/foo/bar:FOO_bar
$
```